# Capturing a line tag

Tags: bash

I want to capture the line `Edymode:` in script heading.  Headings start with `HD` and end in `END OF HD`.  I want to stop looking for matches when the first instance of `END OF HD` is encountered.

```
## HD [Comint]
##  Brief: Print lines in neighbourhood of pattern.
##  File: comint.rc Version 1.0
##  Edymode: BASH
##  Author: Rishi Sunak
## END OF HD [Comint]
```

Currently I have done a simple

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]*##[[:blank:]]*Edymode:' example.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you post what have you tried and where did it failed?

Comment: If it is a script *header*, with GNU `grep` , something like: `grep -m1  Edymode:`

Comment: I would do  it in two steps: First extract using `sed` the whole part between _HD_ and _END OF HD_, and then pipe the outcome into `grep` for finding the _Edymode_ line. You have to think about the expected behaviour, when there is more than one _HD_  and _END OF HD_ line in the file.

Comment: *"Headings start with `HD` and end in `END OF HD`"* -- this is a job for `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to do a simple `g/re/p` (Globally match a Regular Expression and Print the result) use `grep`, when you need to do a simple `s/old/new/` where `old` is a regular expression use `sed`, otherwise for clarity, simplicity, portability, efficiency, and robustness you should use `awk`.

Using any POSIX awk:

```
awk '
    /^[[:blank:]]*##[[:blank:]]*HD/                { gotHd = 1 }
    gotHd && /^[[:blank:]]*##[[:blank:]]*Edymode:/ { print; exit }
    /^[[:blank:]]*##[[:blank:]]*END OF HD/         { exit }
' file
```

or you could get rid of the redundant repeated matching on `^[[:blank:]]*##[[:blank:]]*` with:

```
awk '
    { key = "" }
    match($0,/^[[:blank:]]*##[[:blank:]]*/) {
        key = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    key ~ /^HD/                   { gotHd = 1 }
    gotHd && (key ~ /^Edymode:/)  { print; exit }
    key ~ /^END OF HD/            { exit }
' file
```

Comment: After  finding `##  Edymode: AWK` I want to capture the last word (`AWK`) so I can use that in a case statement. If `AWK` do this, if `BASH` do that.

Comment: You should add this requirement to your question. It's hard to find in the comments.

Comment: @Veak [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged on this forum. Accept an answer to the question you asked and then ask a new question about your additional requirements if you can't figure out how to do that (but given your many other awk questions about far more complex functionality here and at SE from many different accounts, I'd be extremely surprised and concerned about what you're learning from your questions if you can't do that very trivial part on your own).

Answer (score 0):

A simple sed solution:

```bash
$ sed -n '/^## HD/,/^## END OF HD/{/^##  Edymode:/p}' data.txt
##  Edymode: BASH
```

To get the value only:

```bash
$ sed -n '/^## HD/,/^## END OF HD/{s/^##  Edymode: //p}' data.txt
BASH
```

To get the first value only:

```bash
sed -n '/^## HD/,/^## END OF HD/{s/^##  Edymode: //p;tq;b;:q q}'
```

(explanation of the sed magic after the `s` command: if we made a successful substitution - jump to the `:q` label which quits the program, otherwise skip it)

Comment: How can I modify this so that sed captures only the first instance of `/^## HD/,/^## END OF HD/`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk '!_<NF' FS='^.+ Edymode: '
> ```

```
##  Edymode: BASH
```

> ```
> nawk NF RS='^.+ Edymode: |\n.+## END OF HD.+'
> ```

---

> ```
> gawk 'NF *= !_<NF' FS='^.+ Edymode: ' OFS=
> ```

```
BASH
```